# sorting heat map in dc.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dc.js

Using dc.js example (http://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/examples/heat.html) I have managed to bring the layout with a modified dataset. The problem I'm facing here is not knowing how to sort the values.

I have 3 fields in my dataset: `Day_Name, Time, Values`

I have my day names in the csv as "Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", etc.. and Time as 00:00, 01:00, 02:00, 03:00 till 23:00..

Which part of the code should I change to sort the values? Kindly suggest or advise me to correct my code.

Here is my code [in a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ssbs/v0xftcf1/1/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed my data set by having the day name as 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 for the week days and included a HTML code as a legend to it saying that 1 = Sunday, 2 = Monday and so on... 
For now i'm going with this solution.
If i come across on how to sort the week_days, i'll update my answer.

Comment: I think that's the best solution for sorting. You can use [.colsLabel()](http://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/docs/html/dc.heatMap.html#colsLabel) or rowsLabel to change the labels.

Answer (score 0):

On the heatmap, the keys are one axis (eg. Day_name) and the values are the other (Time)

You can use the Acccessor functions

.keyAccessor(function(d) { return +d.key[0]; })
   .valueAccessor(function(d) { return +d.key[1]; })

and use ordering if needed

Comment: I tried and didnt work and i assume that we cannot use + in front of both Key[0] and key[1] as it is a dimension.

Comment: + is simply making sure we are casting the variable to an integer. if it doesn't work, it means you are not providing numbers, it's not about being a dimension or not

Comment: Yes, I'm not providing numbers, i'm providing string values, as mentioned its Day_name: (Sun. Mon, Tue, Wed, Thu, Fri, Sat).